# regex create levels in a li from a select

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Here is my problem. I have a select field.

```
<select id="category_id" onchange="return showCategory(this);" name="data[category_id]">
  <option value="Agencies">More > Agencies</option>
  <option value="Catering">More> Agencies > Catering</option>
  <option value="Freelancers">More > Agencies > Freelancers</option>
  <option value="Driving-Instructors">More > Agencies > Freelancers > Driving Instructors</option>
  <option value="Interior-Designer">More > Agencies > Freelancers > Interior Designer</option>
  <option value="Swimming-Instructor">More > Agencies > Freelancers > Swimming Instructor</option>
</select>
```

What i currently do, is pull into a separate Unordered list each of these. Which then looks like this.

```
<li class="listCat">
            <a href="#">More</a>
            <ul class="More">
                <li></li>

                <li class="More listed_nav">
                    <a href="#">More</a>
                </li>

                <li></li>

                <li class="More listed_nav">
                    <a href="#">More &gt; Agencies</a>
                </li>

                <li></li>

                <li class="More listed_nav">
                    <a href="#">More &gt; Agencies &gt; Catering</a>
                </li>

                <li></li>

                <li class="More listed_nav">
                    <a href="#">More &gt; Agencies &gt; Freelancers</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Here is the JS that accomplishes the task.

```
 $('#category_id option').not(':first-child').each(function(){
       var stripper =  $(this).text();
       var length = $(this).text().split(' ').length;
       var single;
        if(stripper.indexOf('>') === -1){
            //var str = stripper.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g, '');
                single = stripper;
                $('.parentCat .styled_list').append('<li class="listCat "><a href="#">'+single+'</a><ul class="'+single+'"></ul></li>');

            }

    });
    $('div.parentCat ul li').each(function(){
        var liName =  $(this).text();
            $('#category_id option').each(function(){
                var linkAdd = 'http://vizirs.com.sg/listings/index/category/category:'
                var stripper =  $(this).text();


                //console.log(stripper.indexOf().text()).length);
                if (stripper.indexOf(liName) >= 0){

                    stripper.split(' ');

                    //stripper = stripper.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.]+/g," ");
                    stripper = stripper.replace(stripper,'<li class="'+liName+' listed_nav"><a href="#">'+stripper+'</a></li>');
                    var newstripper=stripper.slice(1,stripper.length); 


                    $('ul.'+liName).append('<li>'+stripper+'</li>');

                }
            });
            $(this).find('.listCat ul').each(function(){
                var ulName = $(this).attr('class');
                console.log(ulName);
            });
    });
```

Yes humorous variables.. Here is what ia trying to fix, I need a regex JS that will look at each option, count >, removing the first Word is easy, but after > i need that word to create a new sub menu and put all of those in that Sub Menu. This is the tricky part.  i tried to create several if statements that would look at the first word. But my problem is finding >, and then after that what word there is. Any help is appreciated. thanks!

Comment: can you provide a fiddle? it's pretty hard to demonstrate your problem or what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Regex isn't required here*. Just `split(' > ')` the string to create an array, then loop over that to create the levels in your `li`. * = You could use regex in the `split` if you wanted, but it's not required.

Comment: I attempted split in an earlier version. Im going to try and redo it again. Maybe I was hastened in not using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED BASED ON THE COMMENTS BELOW:**

it was such a challenge but I finally did it: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/R7r5q/8/)**

```
$('#convert').click(function(){
    $('li').each(function(){
        if($(this).html()==''){
            $(this).remove();
        }
        else if($(this).parent().hasClass('styled_list')){
            $(this).children('ul').find('li').each(function(){
                if($(this).html()!=''){
                    var value=$(this).html().split(' &gt; ');
                    if(typeof value[1]!='undefined'){
                        $(this).html('<a href="#">'+value[1]+'</a>');
                        if(typeof value[2]!='undefined'){
                            $(this).append('<ul><li><a href="#">'+value[2]+'</a></li>');
                            if(typeof value[3]!='undefined'){
                                $(this).append('<li><a href="#">'+value[3]+'</a></li></ul>');
                            }
                            else{
                                $(this).append('</ul>');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        $(this).html('<a href="#">'+value[0]+'</a>');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
    $('.listCat ul li').each(function(){
        if($(this).siblings('li').length!=0 && $(this).children('ul').length==0){
            if($(this).children('a').text().indexOf($(this).parent().attr('class'))>=0){
                $(this).remove();
            }
            if($(this).next('li').children('a').text().indexOf($(this).children('a:first').text())>=0){
                $(this).remove();
            }
        }
        if($(this).children('ul').length!=0 && $(this).next('li').children('a').text().indexOf($(this).children('a').text())>=0){
            var that=this;
            $(this).children('ul').children('li').each(function(){
                var value=$(this).html();
                $(that).next('li').children('ul').prepend('<li>'+value+'</li>');
            $(this).parent().remove();
            });
            if($(this).next('li').children('a').text().indexOf($(this).children('a:first').text())>=0){
                $(this).remove();
            }
        }
    });
    $('ul.More li').each(function(){
        if($(this).children('a').text().indexOf('>')>=0){
            $(this).children('a').text($(this).children('a').text().replace(/\n/g,' '));
            var value=$(this).children('a').text().split(' > ');
            $(this).children('a').text(value[0]);
            $(this).append('<ul><li><a href="#">'+value[1]+'</a></li></ul>');
        }
    });
    var content='';
    $('ul.More li').each(function(){
        if($(this).children('a:first').text()=='Freelancers'){
            if($(this).children('ul').length==0){
                $(this).remove();
            }
            else{
                content+=$(this).children('ul').html();
                $(this).remove();
            }
        }
    });
    $('ul.More li:first').children('ul').children('li:first').append('<li><a href="#">Freelancers</a><ul>'+content+'</ul></li>');
});
```

Comment: Awesome job. The first example is the closest. The only problem is, I am trying to figure out is detecting the name. So Freelancers, if there is multiple freelancers, it should put it in a sub list of freelancer which is a sublist of agency.

Comment: I updated your jsfiddle so you could see what I am talking about. http://jsfiddle.net/R7r5q/3/ so for example, it should be something like this, is the main Nav = Bueaty, subnav would be Health, healths navigation would be Doctor and Dentist

Comment: Here is the link to what i have, vizirs.com.sg if you look at the nav, you can see the subnavs are what I am working on.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I really don't understand what you're trying to accomplish! can you give me a better example please?

Comment: I think this should help. The top Nav is what is currently created, the bottom nav is what I am trying to accomplish. http://codepen.io/designsbycamaron/pen/qrFhx

Comment: sorry I've been absent yesterday, I just read your comment, will give you the answer in a few minutes

Comment: but please when you're implementing this into your real code, don't change **ANYTHING**!

Comment: So using what I had, with what you had worked! Awesome thanks man!

Comment: you're welcome, glad it helped, and thank you for asking such an interesting question! ;)

Comment: So Amin, the only thing I had to change, and its my fault I didnt tell you that more gets duplicated, was the last line for freelancers $('li.More').append('<li><a href="#">Freelancers</a><ul>'+content+'</ul></li>'); but everything works awesome. Really appreciate it.